# Edit campaign section via MailChimp API

Tags: python, django, email, mailchimp

Here is what i'm trying to do :

- I create a campaign using a template using Mailchimp editor
- I add a section with a picture and text on the side of the picture on top of the campaign
- The picture and text should be dynamic and filled via the API

I managed to get the campaign content via the Python API and Django.

But the tricky part is how can I dynamically add the content in the campaign ? I dont fully understand how campaigns/update works and how consistently get the added header area to edit (which must be always be retrieved no matter which template is used)

Any pointers ?

Thanks !